# ${\{a\}^{\ast}}^2$ is not ${\{a\}^{\ast}}$

Tags: regular-language, monoid, regular-expressions

I'd like to understand why the language $$(1)\ \ \ ({\{a\}^{\ast}})^2$$ is **not** the same as $$(2)\   \ \ {\{a,b\}^{\ast}}$$
I even don't know what ${\ }^2$ means here.
And why the first language is something like $$\mathbb{( N,+)\times (N,+) }$$
**EDIT** I have omitted $b$ in the formula (2)!

Comment: A guess: it seems to suggest that if $a$ occurs in $\{a\}^*$ then $(a)(a)$ would be part of a word in the language. If this is the case, for example, $aaa$ belongs to the language $\{a\}^*$ but not $(\{a\}^*)^2$

Comment: They seem the same  to me. It depends on what $(\cdot)^2$ means. It could mean 'two dimensional'  elements like $(a,aa)$ whereas the latter is just strings of 'a's.

Comment: Is $\{a\}^*$ the notation of some set in this context? If so that $(\{a\}^*)^2$  might just stand for the Cartesian product.

Comment: Please, see my EDIT. I have omitted $b$ in (2)!

Comment: Perhaps this will help: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/9639

Comment: Well, these two languages ($(\{a\}^*)^2)$ and $\{a,b\}^*$) are different because the alphabet isn't the same...

Comment: @OlivierRoche But they still may be **isomorphic** right ?

Comment: @user3357120 Not if the alphabets don't have the same cardinality I think.

Who are you going to map to the words 'a' and 'b'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have the tag *monoid*, my guess is that in your question, the two occurrences of the word *language* should be changed to *monoid*.

Then your question makes much more sense: the notation $(\{a\}^*)^2$ stands for the monoid $\{a\}^* \times \{a\}^*$, which is indeed isomorphic to the commutative monoid $(\Bbb{N}, +) \times (\Bbb{N}, +)$, but not to the non-commutative monoid $\{a,b\}^*$.

Just for the record, if you really mean languages, then I would interpret $(\{a\}^*)^2$ as the concatenation product $a^*a^*$, which is equal to $a^*$.